# Heating of water by magnetron

Tags: magnetron

I want to know how to calculate heating effects of magnetron.
How much heat will be generated in water by 3kW output 2.45GHz magnetron?

Comment: Stupid question: in your proposed system, where does the energy go that does not get used up by heating the water?

Comment: This depends a lot on geometry. A microwave oven is designed to absorb basically all the power in the water when it is placed in the middle of the oven

Comment: A magnetron is not 100% efficient at delivering RF energy to the target hence, use something that is (such as a kettle element).

Comment: Thanks for help can I assume that water is getting all 3kJ/s of heat?

Comment: @Qwerty it cannot be determined from the details in your question whether the water is getting all the 3 kW.

Comment: A microwave oven is about 65-70% efficient. You can only assume this if your design will be equally efficient.

Comment: @Mattman944 notice that the question asks about a magnetron with a specified *output* power, so that magnetron and supply inefficiencies aren't relevant.